# How to change data on MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is there a way that I can change the duration of the project using vb.net? I tried to record a macro but once I run it it is not doing what I did during the record. it is selecting a different row/col. and also I noticed that the row have negative values, i'm including the macro here.

```
Sub Macro3()
    SelectTaskField Row:=-3, Column:="Actual Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=4, Column:="Actual Duration"
    SelectTaskField Row:=5, Column:="Actual Duration"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-3, Column:="Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-2, Column:="Finish"
    SelectTaskField Row:=1, Column:="Name"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-3, Column:="Actual Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-4, Column:="Actual Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=4, Column:="Actual Start", Height:=1
    SelectTaskField Row:=5, Column:="Actual Start", Height:=1
    SelectTaskField Row:=3, Column:="Actual Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-3, Column:="Duration"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-4, Column:="Actual Start"
    SelectTaskField Row:=-3, Column:="Duration"
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: VB.NET Tag: `DO NOT USE this tag for VB6, VBA, or VBScript questions.`

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to changed the duration using macro, but are there any way that it can be done in a faster way? I read each task, but is there a way of like multiplying all duration by 2 in a faster way?

```
Public Sub toggleMissingBaseline()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim tsks As Tasks
  Dim t As Task
  Dim rgbColor As Long

  Set tsks = ActiveProject.Tasks
    OutlineShowSubTasks
  For Each t In tsks
    OutlineShowSubTasks
    SelectTaskField Row:=t.ID, Column:="Duration", RowRelative:=False
    If (Not t Is Nothing) And (Not t.Summary) Then
         t.Duration = t.Duration * 2
    End If
  Next t
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, remove the `OutlineShowSubTasks` and `SelectTaskField` methods--these are not necessary when looping through the `Tasks` collection. You can also turn off calculation to speed things up.